# Minimizing function with 2 arguments

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to minimize a function with 2 arguments:

```
def c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv):
    return np.abs((4 * eta_gamma * charges**2 * a_q * cf).sum() + 4.* cf *a_tau/3. + a_w * cv)**2/Gamma_gamma

def mu_fv(cf, cv):
    return np.array([cf**4, cf**2 * cv**2, cf**2 * 
c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv), cv**2 * c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv), cf**4, cv**2 * cf**2, cf**2 * cv**2,
                 cv**4, cv**2 * cf**2, cv**4])

def chi_square_fv(cf, cv):
    return ((mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data) @ inv_cov @ (mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data))

x0 = [1., 1.]
res_fv = minimize(chi_square_fv, x0)
```

but, I'm getting the error "TypeError: chi_square_fv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cv'". But, when I do the following:

```
print(chi_square_fv(1.,1.))
```

I get the output

```
38.8312698786
```

I'm not understanding this and I'm new to this type of procedure. How do I proceed? OBS: Gamma_gamma is just a constant of the code.

Comment: You tried ```minimize(chi_square_fv, x0, args=(cv,)```? (assuming you got cv; if not you probably want to prepare your function to unpack x into the variables you need; but that's hard to read out from your incomplete example: the first argument x is always the (flat) vector of decision-variables)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to minimize the function with relation to the 2 arguments. Transforming them into a vector solved the problem. Thank you a lot for your time and your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide us with all the variable values in your code, I would have to guess.

I think the problem is about how you pass in the parameters. `x0 = [1.,1.]` specifies `x0` as a list with 2 values, which is ONE entity. However, in your `chi_square_fv`, the inputs are two separate values rather than a list.

You can try to change your `chi_square_fv` function:

```
def chi_square_fv(clist):
    cf, cv = clist
    return ((mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data) @ inv_cov @ (mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data))
```

Comment: using unpacking can reduce one line though `cf,cv  = clist`

Comment: @Roushan, agreed.

Comment: This worked! Thank you a lot for your time! Now I understand my error!

Answer (score 0):

If you [read docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) on minimize you will find optional `args` argument ( and also see @sacha's comment )

So since your function of two arguments and you want to minimize it across one of them you need to pass values for other's

```
minimize(chi_square_fv, x0, args=(cv,))
```

Which will pass some `cv` value as second parameter to the function `chi_square_fv`